# Image scraping from web pages for character recognition using Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, captcha, object-recognition

I have to gather a dataset of 10,000 captcha images from a website

http://elegalix.allahabadhighcourt.in/elegalix/StartWebSearch.do

You can find the captcha images under the judgment date tab. So I have to scrape 10,000 images from this website using python 3.0 or above and every time you hit judgement date we get a new captcha image. So I have to take in the image and save it has the (6-digit number).jpg/.png.
Any idea how can I do that and please keep in mind after only I hit judgement date/case number/Judge name/title/counsel name I get a new image, **not** by refreshing the page. So anyone can help me with the code?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please, provide your code.

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to this so I haven’t written any.I was trying out beautifulsoup but it was text based scrapping.

Comment: Hey @sentence can you help me here?